# Can I use setof predicate to build a list without duplicates starting from a list with duplicate?

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog for an university exam using SWI Prolog and I have the following exercise:

> Write the duplicates predicate that starting from a ListWithDuplicates
>   list (a list that admit duplicates) build a ListWithoutduplicates
>   (that contain the same elements from the previous list but without
>   duplicates):
>
> **duplicates(ListWithDuplicates, ListWithoutduplicates).**

I think that I have to solve it using the **setof** built in predicate because I have found this exercise in the section related to this argument and because setof create an ordered list without duplicates.

The problem is that I always use **setof** to put into an order list without duplicates some object represented by facts and I don't know how to work on a list...

I have try something like this (but is is wrong and I know it):

```
/* FACT (BASE CASE): If the ListWithDuplicates is empty it is TRUE that the
                     ListWithoutDuplicates is empty:
*/
duplicates([], []).

duplicates(ListWithDuplicates, ListWithoutDuplicates) :-
                         setof(_, ListWithDuplicates, ListWithoutDuplicates).
```

I have try to divide it in two case: a base case: the list withoud duplicated created starting by an empty list it is an empty lust and a rule related to the case in which the ListWithDuplicates is not empty, so ListWithoutDiplicares have to be the result of the setof on the list that admit duplicates...

I have no idea about solve this exercise using setof...is it possible?

Comment: If you read the manual: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'4.30',swi('/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html')) you will see that `setof` applies `sort` on the result of `bagof`. So why not simply sort? but then again, I don't know what the constraints of your exercise are. Anyway, if `sort` is not allowed neither is `setof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setof(X, member(X,List), SortedList).
```

but this is just a round-about way of saying

```
sort(List, SortedList).
```

Comment: Tnx, I think that this is what they ask me...I have no constraint in this exercise...the text of the exercise ask also to create a predicate (that use setof, because the exercise is in the setof section of my slides) that take a list that can contain duplicates and starting from it build an other list that contain the same value without duplicatse...I know that setof predicate induces an ordering between the elements but the text of exercise ask only that the second list contain the same values of the first one without duplicates and don't ask that the order still remain the same...

Comment: If this is indeed what you are asked to do, it is bizarre. In simple words, what you are doing is enumerating the elements of a list using backtracking (`member`), using the `bagof` to create a list from the enumerated elements (which is now identical to the original list), then using `sort` to sort the list, eliminating duplicates. Thus you have made a full round, instead of using `sort` to start with.

Comment: I have understand what you mean. I think that I will ask to my teacher what exactly he would from this exercise...it is an exercise taken from a slide where it is only tread bagof and setof predicate...so I think that to solve it I have to use theme but, as you say, this is not clever...

Comment: It is not: `List = []` fails for the first, but succeeds for `sort/2`.